# Can one use functions that call "test" in bash if statements?

Tags: bash, function, shell, testing, if-statement

To make my scripts more readable I would like to put the tests of my if-then-else-fi statements in a function, such as the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash

function isFileUnderVersionControl() {
  test $( svn info "$1" 2>1 1>/dev/null; echo $? ) -eq 1
}


if isFileUnderVersionControl "$1"
  then
    echo "is under version control
  else
    echo "is not under version control"
fi
```

Is this possible in bash and if so how does one do it correctly ???

Answer (score 2):

No `test` is needed:

```
if svn info "$1" &>/dev/null ; then
    echo Under version control
else
    echo Not under vc
fi
```

Or, if you need the function:

```
function isFileUnderVersionControl() {
    svn info "$1" &>/dev/null
}
if isFileUnderVersionControl "$1" ; then ... fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash functions can only return a status code and nothing else. The *return* statement sets the value of that status code or, if it is absent, the status code is set to that of the last command executed within the function. In this case, it's the test command, and you can check its return status code using the exit status variable *$?*

```
isFileUnderVersionControl "$1"
rc=$?
if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "is under version control"
else
    echo "is not under version control"
fi
```

Comment: that's exactly what `if` does: `if isFileUnderVersionControl "$1" ; then ...`

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose I wasn't clear on what exactly your question was.